# mixed array to string via recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

When I loop through the given array, it suddenly sets back to the beginning:

Here it starts in a classes method:

```
$where = 'WHERE ';
array_walk( $columns, array( &$this, 'walker_cols' ), $where );
```

And this is the callback

```
function walker_cols( $item, $key, &$where )
{
    static $temp;
    if ( is_array( $item ) )
    {
        $temp = $key;
        array_walk( $item, array( __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__ ), $where );
    }

    var_dump($item);
    var_dump($where);

    return $where .= $temp ? "{$temp} = {$item} AND " : "{$key} = {$item} AND ";
}
```

The given Array:

```
$columns = array(
     'assoc_key_a' => 'assoc_val_a'
    ,'assoc_key_b' => array(
         0 => 'num_val_a'
        ,1 => 'num_val_b' 
     )
);
```

The *desired* output:

```
WHERE assoc_key_a = assoc_val_a AND assoc_key_b = num_val_a AND assoc_key_b = num_val_b
```

Now my result from the `var_dump` is the following:

```
input: "assoc_val_a"
output: "WHERE "

input: "num_val_a"
output: "WHERE assoc_key_a = assoc_val_a AND "

input: "num_val_b"
output: "WHERE assoc_key_a = assoc_val_a AND assoc_key_b = num_val_a AND "

input: {
    [0] => "num_val_a"
    [1] => "num_val_b"
}
output: "WHERE assoc_key_a = assoc_val_a     AND "
```

---

If there's another way to come to the desired output, I'd be happy to walk it. I already tried to do it with `array_walk_recursive()`, but with that function I wasn't able to get the `assoc_key_b`, because it directly jumped into the sub-array.

Thanks for any help. *I'm pretty stuck.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer has been simple: I passed the reference on the wrong place.

Call:

```
$where = 'WHERE ';
array_walk( $columns, array( &$this, 'walker_cols' ), $where );
```

Callback:

```
function walker_cols( $item, $key, $where )
{
    static $temp;
    if ( is_array( $item ) )
    {
        $temp = $key;
        // reference to $where added here:
        array_walk( $item, array( &$this, __FUNCTION__ ), &$where );
    }

    var_dump($item);
    var_dump($where);

    return $where .= $temp ? "{$temp} = {$item} AND " : "{$key} = {$item} AND ";
}
```

Comment: Note: It could be that you have to ask `if ( is_array( $item ) ) continue;` a second time. When iterating through the array recursive it _can_ be that you jump right out, so continue so far is the only option.